# Replace vowels with vowel+letter+vowel Python

Tags: python, string, replace

I need to replace vowels with the existing vowel + "r" + vowel (eg.: input: "burger" output: "bururgerer").

It would mean this, but I need to write a program that recognizes the given vowel and repeats it.

```
x = str(input("Please add text: "))  
y = x.replace("a","ara").replace("e", "ere").replace("i", "iri")  
print(y)
```

Comment: And ...? What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Your code should work, except it's still missing a few vowels. What exactly is the question?

Comment: It works but it's not pretty. I do not do it in english and we have twice as much vowels so this replace is very long

Comment: I also tried re.sub but I had trouble with shortening my code, but I got my answer:)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to match any vowel and reference the matched vowel in the replacement string by using a group (`\1`)

```
import re
re.sub('(a|e|i|o|u)', r'\1r\1', 'burger') # 'bururgerer'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through the input and check each character to see if it's a vowel, and then add the 'r' as needed.

```py
x = str(input("Input word: "))
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
y = ''

for letter in range(len(x.lower())):
    if x[letter] in vowels:
        y += x[letter] + 'r' + x[letter]
    else:
        y += x[letter]

print("\n\nOld: ",x)
print("\n\nNew: ",y)
```